# how to add an attribute before returning the node in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I need to return a collection as an attribute of a node. I have a person node that can have several relationships with another person.

[image]

I need to return all the people that follow a person A and return all the relationships between them as an attribute,

this is the query:

```
match (a: Person {email:' a@email.com '}) <- [: FOLLOW] - (x: Person)
with a, x
match (a) - [r] - (x) 
return x, collect (type (r)) as relations;
```

I need to add to the person x, the collection **'relations'** as an attribute of the node 'x'

It is just the opposite to what is explained here: 'https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/updating-a-node-but-returning-its-state-from-before-the-update/', in this case, they return a snapshot but before they update the node, what I really need is to modify the snapshot without actually updating the node, I'm trying:

```
match(a:Person{email:'a@email.com'})<-[:FOLLOW]-(x:Person) 
with a,x
match(a)-[r]-(x)
with properties(x) as snapshot, collect(type(r)) as relations;
set snapshot.relations = relations
RETURN snapshot
```

but when I did it gave me this error: **Expected exactly one statement per query but got: 2**

**UPDATE:** as well said @krishna-reddy eliminating the ';' Fixes the above error, but now it shows this: **Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Type mismatch: expected Node or Relationship but was Map**

Comment: `properties(x)` returns the map of key-value pair of the node properties. Simple solution is to use the `apoc plugin` to create the virtual node add property and return. described in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `APOC plugin` which has procedures for creating [**Virtual Nodes and Relationships**](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#virtual-nodes-rels) which are not stored in the database.

Virtual Nodes and Relationships don’t exist in the graph, they are only returned to the UI/user for representing a graph projection. They can be visualized or processed otherwise.

```
MATCH(a:Person{email:'a@email.com'})<-[:FOLLOW]-(x:Person) 
WITH a,x
MATCH(a)-[r]-(x)
WITH x, collect(type(r)) AS relations
CALL apoc.create.vNode([head(labels(x))], x{.*,relations:relations}) YIELD node AS snapshot
RETURN snapshot
```

Answer (score 1):

```
match(a:Person{email:'a@email.com'})<-[:FOLLOW]-(x:Person) 
with a,x
match(a)-[r]-(x)
with properties(x) as snapshot, collect(type(r)) as relations
set snapshot.relations = relations
RETURN snapshot
```

Just remove ; in line 4.

Comment: very good for the ';' I had not seen it, but now it shows: **Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Type mismatch: expected Node or Relationship but was Map**